# Inner join + Count + Where in Psequel

Tags: count, inner-join, where-clause, psql

New learner here.

I'm working with two tables in : one with publisher data and one with book data.

I'm interested in titles published by a specific publisher in a specific country (ex. Random House, US) within an `INNER JOIN` with `WHERE` clause. So far so good:

```
SELECT 
book_infotable.tblbook_title, 
tblpublisher_publisher,
tblpublisher_country 
FROM book_infotable
INNER JOIN pub_infotable 
ON book_infotable.pubid = pub_infotable.pubid
WHERE tblpublisher_publisher = 'Oxford University Press' AND 
tblpublisher_country = 'GB';
```

I'd like to add `COUNT` to this to count the number of titles published by a specific publisher's office.

[goal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXF2V.png)

But, when I try the following with `COUNT`,

```
SELECT COUNT(tblbook_title) 
AS title_count, pub_infotable.tblpublisher_publisher, tblpublisher_country 
FROM book_infotable 
INNER JOIN pub_infotable 
ON book_infotable.pubid = pub_infotable.pubid 
WHERE tblpublisher_publisher = 'Knopf' AND tblpublisher_country = 'GB'
GROUP BY pub_infotable.tblpublisher_publisher, tblpublisher_country, 
book_infotable.tblbook_title;
```

I wind up with

[table with persistent "1s" in count column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbpVN.png)

Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try executing this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS title_count, tblpublisher_publisher, tblpublisher_country 
from (
SELECT pub_infotable.tblpublisher_publisher AS tblpublisher_publisher, 
tblpublisher_country 
FROM book_infotable 
INNER JOIN pub_infotable 
ON book_infotable.pubid = pub_infotable.pubid 
WHERE tblpublisher_publisher = 'Oxford University Press' AND 
tblpublisher_country = 'GB'
GROUP BY book_infotable.tblpublisher_publisher, tblpublisher_country, 
book_infotable.tblbook_title ) temp 
GROUP BY tblpublisher_publisher, tblpublisher_country;
```

Comment: When I execute this query, I get an error saying "column tblpublisher_publisher does not exist" Is it because tblpublisher_publisher is in the pub_infotable rather than the book_infotable?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it! I wound up using

```
SELECT pub_infotable.tblpublisher_publisher,
 COUNT(book_infotable.tblbook_title) AS title_count
  FROM book_infotable
 INNER JOIN pub_infotable 
        ON book_infotable.pubid = pub_infotable.pubid
   WHERE tblpublisher_publisher = 'Oxford University Press' AND tblpublisher_country = 'GB'
 GROUP BY pub_infotable.tblpublisher_publisher;
```